# h20.init() Not working giving h20connectionerror and h20startuperror

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, h2o

Hey I am using anaconda environment, and have successfully installed h20-py library and all. It's just that when I try to run h2o.init() it gives me the following error

---

```
H2OConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/h2o.py in init(url, ip, port, https, insecure, username, password, cookies, proxy, start_h2o, nthreads, ice_root, enable_assertions, max_mem_size, min_mem_size, strict_version_check, ignore_config, extra_classpath, **kwargs)
    251                                      _msgs=("Checking whether there is an H2O instance running at {url}",
--> 252                                             "connected.", "not found."))
    253     except H2OConnectionError:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py in open(server, url, ip, port, https, auth, verify_ssl_certificates, proxy, cookies, verbose, _msgs)
    317             conn._timeout = 3.0
--> 318             conn._cluster = conn._test_connection(retries, messages=_msgs)
    319             # If a server is unable to respond within 1s, it should be considered a bug. However we disable this

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py in _test_connection(self, max_retries, messages)
    587             raise H2OConnectionError("Could not establish link to the H2O cloud %s after %d retries\n%s"
--> 588                                      % (self._base_url, max_retries, "\n".join(errors)))
    589 

H2OConnectionError: Could not establish link to the H2O cloud http://localhost:54321 after 5 retries
[06:14.50] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54321): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Cloud (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd0f913b390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))
[06:14.71] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54321): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Cloud (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd0f913ba58>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))
[06:14.92] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54321): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Cloud (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd1186fd160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))
[06:15.14] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54321): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Cloud (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd1186fd828>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))
[06:15.35] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54321): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Cloud (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd1186fdef0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

H2OStartupError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-95453bf1556d> in <module>
----> 1 h2o.init()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/h2o.py in init(url, ip, port, https, insecure, username, password, cookies, proxy, start_h2o, nthreads, ice_root, enable_assertions, max_mem_size, min_mem_size, strict_version_check, ignore_config, extra_classpath, **kwargs)
    259             raise H2OConnectionError('Can only start H2O launcher if IP address is localhost.')
    260         hs = H2OLocalServer.start(nthreads=nthreads, enable_assertions=enable_assertions, max_mem_size=mmax,
--> 261                                   min_mem_size=mmin, ice_root=ice_root, port=port, extra_classpath=extra_classpath)
    262         h2oconn = H2OConnection.open(server=hs, https=https, verify_ssl_certificates=not insecure,
    263                                      auth=auth, proxy=proxy,cookies=cookies, verbose=True)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/backend/server.py in start(jar_path, nthreads, enable_assertions, max_mem_size, min_mem_size, ice_root, port, extra_classpath, verbose)
    110         hs = H2OLocalServer()
    111         hs._verbose = bool(verbose)
--> 112         hs._jar_path = hs._find_jar(jar_path)
    113         hs._extra_classpath = extra_classpath
    114         hs._ice_root = ice_root

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/backend/server.py in _find_jar(self, path0)
    204                 return jp
    205         raise H2OStartupError("Cannot start local server: h2o.jar not found. Paths searched:\n" +
--> 206                               "".join("    %s\n" % s for s in searched_paths))
    207 
    208     @staticmethod

H2OStartupError: Cannot start local server: h2o.jar not found. Paths searched:
    /Users/sharozearcher/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/backend/bin/h2o.jar
    /Users/sharozearcher/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/h2o_jar/h2o.jar
    /usr/local/h2o_jar/h2o.jar
    /Users/sharozearcher/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/local/h2o_jar/h2o.jar
    /Users/sharozearcher/.local/h2o_jar/h2o.jar
    /Users/sharozearcher/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/h2o_jar/h2o.jar
```

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I'm using Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Do you have the Java `h2o` server running? The python library is only used to interact with the server, it doesn't install the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `conda install -c h2oai h2o` in new environment and everything works fine for me.

It seems that you have installed only client version of the package which does not include h2o.jar. Can you provide your commands to reproduce it?